# reaching a weblogic web-app over internet

Tags: web, webserver, weblogic, java-ee-5

On a project I’m working on at my current job, I’ve come across a pernicious problem. 
We have an internal web-app runs at say, **1.1.1.1:123/webapp**. Customer wants to reach the web-app over **www.webapp.com**.

Internet server port forwarded to local server. so when i call **www.webapp.com:123/webapp** i can reach the app, but how can i reach the app just by www.webapp.com?

We are using weblogic server 11g and java 1.5 application

thanks in advance

Comment: Basically you need to have a server listening on port 80. You can configure [OHS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/index-091236.html)  on 80 port [infront of weblogic](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2009/09/23/configure-oracle-http-server-infront-of-oracle-weblogic-server-mod_wl_ohs/). You can also configure BIG IP to route the traffic, I have not used it before though.